# PHP OOP Gracefull __autoload failure

Tags: php, oop

Say I have the following:

```
function __autoload($class) { 
    if(file_exists("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/etc/".strtolower($class).".php")) { 
        require_once strtolower($class).".php"; 
        return true;
    } else {echo "failed";}
} 

class test {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Database();
        $this->auth = new Authentications();
    }
}

$t = new test();
```

The file `authentications.php` does not exist.  However I want to be able to handle that gracefully, at the moment I get the following output:

> failed Fatal error: Class 'Authentications' not found in core.php on
>   line 15

How can I handle this gracefully? I want to be able to output my own error or carry on - whichever I choose.

Comment: If none of your autoload functions finds anything, then you can't handle it "gracefully". You get the fatal error unless the class was declared in some way.

Comment: There is no way? There must be a way!

Comment: Explain what you would like to happen. (Declare a shallow stub class instead?)

Comment: I want to be able to output my own error or carry on - whichever I choose.

Comment: You can `try`/`catch (Error $e)` such things in PHP7. Right now it's a *fatal* error.

Comment: I tried that, But I am pretty sure the __autoload function can't throw an error back inside the `test` class.  Either way I didn't manage to get it work

Comment: With PHP7. Other approach (which you didn't ask for): loading and probing per [`class_exists`](http://php.net/class_exists).